# Auto filling a text box by value from combo box

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a text box (txtFailGroupName) that's supposed to display data from a specific table (tblFailGroups) but I want it to display data based on a value from a combo box (cmbFailType) which displays data from a table (tblFails) and there is a relationship between the two tables
I hope someone can help to resolve the problem
This is the code I used for filling combobox:

```
dtFailType.Clear()
    adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from tblFails", con)
    adapter.Fill(dtFailType)
    cmbFixType.DataSource = dtFailType
    cmbFixType.DisplayMember = "FailName"
    cmbFixType.ValueMember = "FailID"
    cmbFixType.ResetText()
```

Comment: Please add some illustrative code in your question.

Comment: Maybe try describing the relationship between the tables too.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Edit the question and add all the information that should have been there in the first place.

Comment: Does the `tblFails` have a field, maybe something like FailGroupID, that is a foreign key that is tied to a Primary Key in `tblFailGroups`?